# CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials always authorizes request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-7.5, kerberos

I have a Winforms app that sends request to an ASP.NET app that is hosted on IIS.

I have Windows authentication enabled and authorization given to a specific domain group.

When I send requests from the browser I'm prompted to login. If I supply a user that is not in the group, then the prompt just comes up again. If I use a different method of sending requests like httprepl or with python, I get 401 Unauthorized.

My Winforms app will get 401 Unauthorized if either I don't supply credentials or supply incorrect credentials.

However when I use `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`, the request from my Winforms returns success with the correct returned content.

But the user I am using is not in the group. Why is it authorizing? Furthermore when I look at the `CredentialCache` object, I see no values for user or password. The `PreAuthenticate` setting seems to not matter either when I use `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials`

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
                                       { 
                                           Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials, 
                                           PreAuthenticate = true 
                                       });
```

And if it matters, the application pool identity is not a part of the group either.

It's possible that I ran the application once when the user was in the group, but why would subsequent attempts work even after I removed the user from the group?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.0, IIS 7.5, and .NET 7.0 for the Winforms app.

Comment: If you have the source code of that ASP.NET Core application, you should debug your server side to learn what's wrong with your authorization settings. `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` does nothing more than use the Windows logon user credentials for authentication, so whether to authorize access is only controlled by your ASP.NET Core side.

Comment: @LexLi I think once authenticated and authorized, that state gets cached somewhere in IIS or the ASP.NET application itself because I tried again now, which is around 10 hours later, and now it is working as intended with the user not in the group.

Comment: But that's still a server side issue you should chase down, or sometime in the future it will happen again.

Comment: @LexLi Ya but I never claimed it was a client issue. In fact I wrote the question hoping someone could give me some setting I can configure in web.config or programmatically in the the ASP.NET app.

Comment: From the question itself, you provide little information about the server side (except it is ASP.NET Core). So, if you expect any help on that part, make sure you describe it the right way (especially showing how you configure authentication and authorization in code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that the authorization to the ASP.NET app is dependent on a specific AD group.

Since the original Kerberos ticket does not have this new group membership information, the membership changes I was making didn't have any effect.

For the user group membership to be correctly communicated to the server, a new Kerberos ticket needs to generated. This can happen if the user were to logoff and log back in, or after the ticket expires (8 hours in my case).

So I just logged off and logged back in.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can also "Purge Tickets" using the Windows 'Kerb Tray' utility.

Comment: @DennisVM-D2i. I tried purging and generating a new one by running a new shell with the user. When I checked the newly generated ticket in this second shell, it all seemed fine, but once I closed the shell, it wasn't. There was a new ticket, but with the old configuration.